# Tinyfilemanager upload from URL permissions

Tags: url, upload

I have a problem after upload image from URL:

- Preview thumbnail doesn't work
- Direct Link doesn't work, I get Forbidden error
  But image file exists in my storage...
  Upload from URL was set to permission 0600 and upload image from file is set 0644, it's a problem about permissions, I can resolve this with default 0644 permissions after upload?
  Thank you everyone!

Upload from file wotks well with default permissions 0644

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: did you ever solve this? i have same issue.